# Redirect to current page after login when clicking (jQuery)

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create a jquery function which redirects to login page when clicking a div element and then redirect to current page after login in WordPress:

```
jQuery('.tologinpage').click(function(){
    alert('Please login');
window.location.href='<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>';
});
```

For this purpose, in php, the following code needs to be used to redirect to current page after login:

```
<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>
```

Is it possible to add the above php code into the jquery code?

(When I use "window.location.href='/wp-login.php', it directs to dashboard.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First console this url and then check weather its right or wrong then proceed further.

```
var redirect_url = "<?php echo wp_login_url( home_url() ); ?>";
//console.log(redirect_url);

jQuery('.tologinpage').click(function(){
    alert('Please login');
window.location.href= redirect_url;
});
```